# How to Replace a Textbox and Button with just a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, textbox

This is difficult for me to explain but I will try.
I have an html document and an external jQuery file.
The jQuery file creates a table with grid references (unsure if that is correct term).
The table has 12 rows and 24 columns.
The grid starts at 0,0 for the top-left cell and ends at 11,23 for the bottom-right cell

There is a button which gets values from a text box (in the form 0,1 or 0,2 etc).
This value is then passed to a script on the html page which the calls an external jQuery file.
This returns the value of the cell from the jQuery table (which is either 0 or 1) and outputs it to the page.
The cell value correlates to the background color of the cell (e.g. white (1) or blue (0)).

This all works very well as it is but I want to replace the text box and programmatically enter its value.
The value will never change so the text box is a waste of real estate. Eventually it will be passing a range of cell values (but I am way off from attempting that as I will have to edit the jQuery file).
So clicking the button will use a value from a variable/s in the html document instead of the text box.

Somehow I need to pass the textbox id and value to the button code (so it runs the function later on the page).
I am guessing I need to use another function which I have attempted but it is confusing having to pass the id and the value (and I cannot pass even one of them).
Of course, if I delete the text box I get errors in the console:

```
(TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined).
```

The text box (which I want to remove) and button (with my added function call):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="0,0" id="J_cellIndex" value="0,0"/><button class="J_sheetControl" id="J_timingGetCol" onclick="TheCell(this.J_cellIndex)">
```

The function (as I have it now, which I know is very well off the mark and passes nothing to the button):

```
function TheCell(J_cellIndex){

var J_cellIndex = "0,6"

  console.log(J_cellIndex);
}
```

The script:

```
$("#J_timingGetCol").click(function(ev){
            var cellIndex = $("#J_cellIndex").val().split(',');
            var cellData = sheet.getColState(cellIndex);
            var $dataDisplay = $("#J_dataDisplay") ;
            $dataDisplay.html("<b>Cell Data At ["+cellIndex+"] : </b>"+cellData);
        });
```

Comment: Maybe this is not possible to do? Maybe just hide the textbox would be the best solution? Then enter the values statically in it.

Comment: No, that will not work, Hiding the text box part hides the button too. At least I see now how they are linked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store your values. You can add `data attributes` to any DOM element you need (`tr`, `td`, `button`, or any other per your needs). There is indeed no good reason to store these values in an `input` element if you're not expecting any user input.

Here is how you can utilize the `data attributes` in your script (you dont even need jQuery):

```
//Note the added data-value attribute//
<button data-value="0,1" class="J_sheetControl" id="J_timingGetCol" onclick="TheCell(this.J_cellIndex)">

//Getting the data and the values//
var button = document.querySelector('#J_timingGetCol');
var buttonDataSet = button.dataset;
var cellIndex = buttonDataSet.value.split(',');
...use the cellIndex as before
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works well. I found I do not even need the function I created at all. So I deleted that and removed the reference from the button. Now I just change the value of data-value in the button code and I can get the cell value I require. Now to investigate how I can put this all into a loop and get the value of 6 cells in that same column (0,0 to 5,0). Thanks again.